# Вопрос по Thread и InputStream

Tags: java, многопоточность, потоки-данных

Господа, подскажите пожалуйста. Обязательно ли делать:

```
 mInputStream.close();
 mOutputStream.close();
```

После получения необходимых данных. Если не закрывать, чем это грозит?

И ещё вопросик, Thread циклично запускается в RepeatingAlarmService - 
если не останавливать в конце класса (после получения данных) вот так:

```
mReadThread.interrupt();
```

то в следующем цикле RepeatingAlarmService происходит:

```
mReadThread = new ReadThread();       
mReadThread.start();
```

запуск нового потока или он понимает что поток уже запущен и игнорирует запуск нового Thread?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Закрывать не обязательно. Но если не закрыть, грозит утечкой памяти, и проблемами с производительностью (так как будет постоянно висеть и потреблять ресурсы). По поводу второго то он запустит новый поток.

Comment: Скажите, а вот это исправит ситуацию:   if (mReadThread == null) {
           mReadThread = new ReadThread();       
               mReadThread.start();  
           }